# ¿«Pièce de résistance» se usa en español?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, extranjerismos, francés

En inglés no es raro usar expresiones de procedencia francesa cuando es adecuado. «Pièce de résistance» es una de estas frases bien conocidas en el mundo angloparlante.

¿Se puede usar la frase francesa «pièce de résistance» en español?

¿O no sería entendido en ningún lado?

Comment: He escrito una respuesta pero no estoy seguro de con qué significado quieres utilizar "pièce de résistance". Si añades un ejemplo, puedo considerarlo también en la respuesta.

Comment: That's weird, because it's French, but I never heard it in French. Maybe it's just me, but I think it's not a very common expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En España, *pièce de résistance* no se dice nunca. Se puede decir "plato fuerte" para referirse al plato más importante en una comida:

- El plato fuerte es pollo asado

o "la mejor parte", "lo mejor de todo" si se habla en sentido figurado de "la parte más interesante o sorprendente de una historia":

- Y ahora viene lo mejor de todo: habían ido a la guardería juntos hace 20 años.

Comment: Definitivamente me gusta "plato fuerte", utilizado inclusive en sentido figurado: *La charla de Bill Gates fue el **plato fuerte** del evento*.

Answer (score 3):

Para alguien que conoce este término, es difícil resistir la tentación de usarlo en la escritura y la conversación -- en su momento adecuado -- pero se usa en forma traducida.  He aquí dos ejemplos:

[image: foto de la pianista cubana]

> Aplauso tardío a Ivette Hernández
>
> [...] La Sonata de Liszt, la pieza de resistencia del programa, exige un
> poco más que modales musicales correctos, y aquí la señorita Hernández
> sonaba como una pequeña escolar. A menudo le daba tanta importancia a
> los detalles, como a la sustancia temática y estructural primaria;
> mientras, su tono parecía desnutrido para un trabajo tan épico. ([fuente](http://www.desmemoriados.com/aplauso-tardio-a-ivette-hernandez/))

[image]

> La Pieza de Resistencia
>
> MATERIALES NATURALES. Los collares largos de corales con pieza central
> de jade, el collar largo de piedras de onyx con cuentas doradas y el
> collar corto de cuatro vueltas de corales son de Carmen Chauny.
>
> Los collares statement se han convertido en los protagonistas
> indiscutibles de la temporada y el objeto deseado de las amantes de la
> moda. [fuente](http://ellosyellas.com.pe/tendencias/moda/la-pieza-de-resistencia-1be4)

Hay que mencionar también la película "The Lego Movie", que cuenta con una *pieza de resistencia*.  En la versión en inglés, le pusieron el nombre "piece of resistance" (no me preguntes por qué), pero en español pusieron una traducción más razonable, "pieza de resistencia."  La escena donde Emmet encuentra la pieza de resistencia y el narrador nos informa de ello: [aquí](https://youtu.be/r4SFsSSCN2w?t=120). Y la imagen (creo que la Pieza de Resistencia es el rectángulo rojo):

[image: la pieza de resistencia de Lego]

Es posible que la película ayudará a popularizar el término -- pero también es posible que siga escondido en el lenguaje erudito.

Answer (score 1):

La respuestas es **no**.  Hace ya varias decenas de años que el uso de expresiones o frases hechas en francés dejó de ser uso común en el lenguaje (en lenguaje culto, por supuesto, que es el ámbito al que se restringía la utilización de dichas frases).

Aún pueden encontrarse, sin embargo, expresiones de este tipo en traducciones con cierta solera de obras que originalmente se habían escrito en inglés, al ser común el uso de expresiones francesas en este tipo de textos (el texto inglés se tradujo, pero se dejaron las expresiones francesas tal cual, a veces acompañadas como mucho de notas del traductor).  Sin embargo, para el lector actual resultan construcciones arcaicas.